# How can we use offline caching in iOS development?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, offline-caching

I'm building an article reading iOS app.

Articles load by `JSON` data and app containing `UITableView` with images and text.

I want to use *offline caching* to increase the performance of app.

What is the best way of offline caching in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `KCSCachedStore` to store cached data. You can find that here...http://devcenter.kinvey.com/ios/guides/caching-offline

The link contains the API and tutorials + references.

Answer (score 0):

"The best" will always be different based on opinions of what people have used.  I've used (and would use again) Apple's [NSCache](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html) framework.

Comment: That for in memory data only.